# Retrieving data from a single column in a local database in C#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I'm trying to create a local database file (for a school assignment) and I've managed to get the database working (I can add new data to it etc.), the database file is in the .mdf format.

There is one thing I'm getting stuck on. It's hard for me to explain how it works exactly (I recently started programming) so I will post a link to the video that I used to make my database:
[video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EpYqtSlOr8&list=FLzFdyr0vHDFYQxWdkvh7qGw&index=18).

I got it working to the point that I'm able to search for a value in a certain database column (it searches for a color). After I executed the search only one row is visible in the DataGridView. Then I have to retreive the value (in this case it is text / a string) of another column in the same row.

[This is the project I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kfqe.jpg), I can't post the image right here because I don't have a high enough reputation.

I will explain what happens at each step:

1. In the textbox that's in between the button and label I can type the color I want to search for. After I press the button it's going to search for that value in the column that you see at 2.
2. After the search has been executed only one row with the value I've searched for will be visible.
3. Then it should take the value / data from the column 'Voornaam' (which means name) from that row.
4. The name that is in the column should be placed in the textbox you see at 4.

   ```
   // btnZoeken is the search button I use at 1
   private void btnZoeken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       /* Klantengegevens is the name of my table which means something like customer data, 
       tbGevraagdekleur is the textbox that I use at 1. */

       this.klantengegevensTableAdapter.Fillby(this._Lock_IT_DatabaseDataSet.Klantengegevens, tbGevraagdekleur.text);

       /* tbVoornaam is the textbox I used at 4., the name that has been placed in the 'Voornaam'
          column should become visible in this textbox.
       */

       tbVoornaam.text = this.klantengegevensTableAdapter.GetData().VoornaamColumn.ToString();
   }
   ```

The code does place a value in the textbox at 4. but the text of the textbox gets the same value as the name of the column (which is 'Voornaam'). It should be an actual name like Mark or Joshua.

I hope I explained it good enough, you shouldn't pay attention to all the other buttons that you see in the form.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
 DataTable theTable = new DataTable();
 this.klantengegevensTableAdapter.Fill(theTable);
 tbVoornaam.text = theTable.Rows[0]["Voornaam"].ToString();
```

The reason you are getting "Voornaam" as the text is because that is the constant value stored in the variable VoornaamColumn when what you really want is the value from that column, the code above gives you that for the first row in the dataset.-@krystanhonour

EDIT try this:

```
DataSet da= new DataSet();
DataTable theTable = new DataTable();
da.Tables.Add(theTable);
     this.klantengegevensTableAdapter.Fill(da.Tables[0]);
     tbVoornaam.text = da.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Voornaam"].ToString();
```

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for my lack of explanation of code. Thank you @krystanhonour

Comment: original comment added to your answer

Comment: I get an error message saying that the argument that 'theTable' in the second line of code you gave me is invalid. And @krystanhonour thanks for editing my original post

Comment: the TableAdapter provides the communication from my application to my database (and the other way around I guess). It also handles the  queries I can make (one was used to make the search function possible).http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx

Comment: I still get an error message saying that the argument is invalid when using (da.Tables[0])

Comment: I will try something with the suggestions you gave me, thanks! I'll let you know when I manage to get it working.